# How to change default return type of action filter in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

In asp.net MVC i want to set some other default type instead of ActionResult of controller.like whenever i create a new controller , it will always have different return type.for eg:

this is default code block :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
         {
            //some code
         }
```

and when i create new Controller, it will always be like

the new default code block should look like :

```
      public NewDefaultClass Details(int id)
          {
            //some code
          }
```

how can i achieve this. can anyone help me?

Comment: @philter i thinks it not

Comment: Are you sure this is what you mean? ActionResult is not like a `car` or a `person` it's more like a "message". Are you not going to be returning messages? If you want to change, can you create your `CustomActionResult` and inherit from `ActionResult`?

Comment: i want some class relevant to ActionResult and then set it to default so that whenever i create a new controller then it should automatically creates the actions which has return types of the class/object i created. @Jonathan

Comment: @Jonathan i got it. in visual studio 2017 navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\Web API\1033\WebApiControllerItemTemplatev5.0.cs" for editing template for web API or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC\1033" for editing template for MVC.there we can add code for editing template. Code will Look like
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemname$ : ApiController
    {  public Response Get()
  {}    }
 public class Response{}
}

Comment: @Jonathan for visual studio 2015 navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\WebAPI\CSharp\1033\WebApiApplicationv5.0\Controllers" for editing template for web API